# Inheritance Fluent Builder with reference back to parent?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Not sure I am doing this correctly but essentially I have an object `Foo` which has heaps of configurations. I am using the Fluent Builder pattern to set the params as it makes it easier to mix & match. Once the parameters are set I wish to essentially "run" the analysis...

The complication is with the `Bar` object which is a slightly different calculation method uses a combined set of the `Foo` params + `Bar` params.

My initial thoughts is to have an abstract calculation class `BaseCalc` which contains common calculations and set either `FooCalc` or `BarCalc` which contains the custom calculations depending if `AddBar` is called.

```
     analysis = new FooBuilder()
                    .SetData(data)
                    .SetParam1("Foo")
                    .AddBar(builder => builder                        
                        .SetParam2("Bar")
                        )         
                .Build();

    public class FooBuilder: IFooBuilder
    {
      private readonly Foo foo;
      public IFooBuilder SetData(List<int> data)
      {
        foo.source = data;
        return this;
      }

      public IFooBuilder SetParam1(string param)
      {
        foo.param1 = param;
        return this;
      }

      public IFooBuilder(AddBar(Action<IBarBuilder> configure)
      {
        var builder = new BarBuilder();
        configure(builder);
        foo.Bar = builder.Build();
        return this;
      }
    }

public abstract class BaseCalc
{
  public abstract void Run();
}

public class FooCalc : BaseCalc
{ 
  public override void Run()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This should be Param1 Foo");
  }
}

public class BarCalc : BaseCalc
{ 
  public override void Run()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This should be Param1 Foo + Param2 Bar");
  }
}
```

As an example if I called `analysis.Run()` in the example above it would run `BarCalc.Run()` using both `Foo` and `Bar`

Comment: if Foo is Bar aware, then I'd just have a single calc method that has conditionals for simplicity. If Foo is not Bar aware then it sounds like the calculations are independent of both, and should be in a FooBarCalc class that accepts Foos and Bars built using your builders?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD Not code improvement but I am trying to design in a way that allows for separation of concerns and the ability to extend in the future with different calculation methods

Comment: Please, share the minimal reproducible sample with `Run()` method and `FooCalc`/`BarCalc`